# Handling events in a Xamarin ControlTemplate

Tags: xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I'm trying to handle an event on a control in a `ControlTemplate`. I'm using the `ControlTemplate` as a way of creating a custom navigation page. I've designed a few controls within the header in the `ControlTemplate` and I've added a `TapGesture` to my back button image which routes to a method in the page class. I've tried doing this multiple ways but I simply can't get it to fire an event. Firstly, I tried adding the `ControlTemplate` to the `App.xaml` file with an event declared in `App.xaml.cs` - no event fired.

I then tried creating another `ContentPage` with its own `ControlTemplate` with a `TapGesturizer` declared in that class. No event fired. I then tried getting hold of the Image control in the constructor of the page (which I managed to do), so I could programmatically add the Tap Gesturizer. No event fired.

Does anyone have any idea of how to handle an event defined within a ControlTemplate? Ben on this for 3 days now and one step short of pulling my hair out!

Thanks